# Triggering submit button using session variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am passing a Boolean value from one page to another using session variables in PHP , the second page is meant to display results if the form is submitted , I want to trigger the submit button if the Boolean is true and display results automatically ,(echo) but if false the page should show up as its meant to. As I'm new here, please help! Also, I am not familiar with Ajax.

Thanks

```
 <?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['answer'])) {

 $v11=$_SESSION['answer'];//boolean value
 }

 $q=100;
 $f=200;
 $r=300;



  ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../styles/messages.css"             />

  <html>

  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<form action=""  name = "page0" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-    data">
  <tr >
  <td  colspan=  > ID </td><br>
 <td  colspan="2" size="30"> NAME </td>
 <td  colspan="3" size="50" > MACH </td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td  colspan=><input type="text" name="ID" class="rw" value="<?php       $phpvar=$v11; echo $phpvar; ?>"></td> 
 <td colspan="2" ><input type="text"  name="NAME" class="rw" size="30" value="<?php $phpvar=$f; echo $phpvar; ?>"></td>
 <td colspan="2"><input type="text"  name="MACH" class="rw" size="70"    value="<?php $phpvar=$r; echo $phpvar; ?>"></td>

 </tr>
 <input type="submit" button class="button" value="Calculate" name="second_call" onclick= "document.write('<?php hello(); ?>');"  /> 
</form>
</table>
 </html>
  <?php 
 function  hello()
  {
  //some operation using values q, f, r
  echo(result);
  //i want this echo to work when i click submit on the previous page   from       where im redirecting here if v11=true
 } 


 ?>
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to get what you want to do without any code.
If you want a page to 'echo' something if Session Variable is 'true' 
and display the page contents if it's not, i'd suggest the following most simple way :

```
    <?php

$session_value = $_SESSION["mySessionVariable"];

if { $session_value ) {
    // echo something 
}else {
    // include the php file with the "normal" page 
}

?>
```

Comment: there are some calculations happening on the redirected page which happens only when the submit button is triggered , the output of the redirected page is to be echoed!